# Reduce stock only for specific order statuses and payment method in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, orders

I'm working on a bit of custom Woocommerce functionality for a client. They use the BACS payment gateway to handle manual payments.

However, the gateway currently reduces the stock too early for our needs, i.e., when the order is "On Hold". I would like to ONLY reduce the stock when the order is marked "Processing" or "Complete" (avoiding duplicate reductions).

I have manged to prevent the stock from reducing itself while "on hold" with the following snippet:

```
function wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock( $reduce_stock, $order ) {
if ( $order->has_status( 'on-hold' ) ) {
$reduce_stock = false;
}
return $reduce_stock;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', 'wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock', 10, 2 );
```

I'm not too sure how to proceed though. While the above code works, adding the following condition does not:

```
else if ( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) || $order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) {
$reduce_stock = true;
}
```

In short, I'd ideally like the stock to change depending on the following stock statuses:

- On Hold - Does nothing
- Completed or Processing - Reduce Stock (Only once)
- Cancelled - Increase Stock (Only if initially reduced)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_order_status_changed`** you will be able to target 'processing' and 'completed' order statuses change reducing order items stock.

I have added in your function a condition to target only "BACS" payment gateway on orders.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', 'wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock', 10, 2 );
function wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock( $reduce_stock, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status( 'on-hold' ) && $order->get_payment_method() == 'bacs' ) {
        $reduce_stock = false;
    }
    return $reduce_stock;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'order_stock_reduction_based_on_status', 20, 4 );
function order_stock_reduction_based_on_status( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    // Only for 'processing' and 'completed' order statuses change
    if ( $new_status == 'processing' || $new_status == 'completed' ){
    $stock_reduced = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_stock_reduced', true );
        if( empty($stock_reduced) && $order->get_payment_method() == 'bacs' ){
            wc_reduce_stock_levels($order_id);
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works

Comment: Appreciate it! I added a slightly modified version of the code shared over here: https://github.com/kloon/woocommerce-auto-restore-stock/blob/master/woocommerce-auto-stock-restore.php in order to achieve  the stock restore functionality, should the order be cancelled after it's marked Complete or Processing.

Comment: @ConorCampbell The stock restore functionality will work as in any other order kind. In woocommerce, when order is cancelled, normally, it will check for the flag '_order_stock_reduced' and will reduce stock…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I think there is an issue on the code, because when the order gets on hold or processing changes the order metadata _order_stock_reduced to yes anyway, then will not pass the condition empty($stock_reduced)

Comment: oh ok, I maybe miss understood the first message.
How do you think will be a good way to decrease stock only for a specific status? (like shipped status)

Comment: @Guido it should be better to ask a new question adding to it the code for your custom status and a link to this thread explaining what you are trying to achieve in details. Also add your code attempt explaining what doesn't work…

Comment: This did not work for me. It avoided reducing the stock when `bacs` was selected, but it doesn't reduce the stock when changing the order status to `processing` or `completed`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me. The first part did but not the second, this is how I modified it:

```php
// This is the same as the accepted answer
add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', 'wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock', 10, 2 );
function wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock( $reduce_stock, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status( 'on-hold' ) && $order->get_payment_method() == 'bacs' ) {
        $reduce_stock = false;
    }
    return $reduce_stock;
}

// This is what I changed
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'reduce_stock_on_bacs_order_status_change', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'reduce_stock_on_bacs_order_status_change', 10, 1 );
function reduce_stock_on_bacs_order_status_change( $order_id ) {
  // Get the order object
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  
  // Check if the order was paid using BACS
  if ( 'bacs' == $order->get_payment_method() ) {
    // Check if the stock reduction has already been done for this order
    $stock_reduction_done = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_stock_reduction_done', true );
    if ( ! $stock_reduction_done ) {
      // Iterate over the order items
      foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        // Reduce stock for each item
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $qty = $item->get_quantity();
        $product->reduce_stock( $qty );
      }
      
      // Mark the stock reduction as done for this order
      update_post_meta( $order_id, '_stock_reduction_done', true );
    }
  }
}
```

This will not reduce the stock for `BACS` payments until the order is marked as `processing` or `completed`.