# Avoid stock reduction on COD orders with proscessing status in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, stock

I am having trouble with my COD payment method, when a customer orders... The order becomes processing and it reduces the items stock.

Based on this answer thread: [Reduce stock only for specific order statuses and payment method in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863990/reduce-stock-only-for-specific-order-statuses-and-payment-method-in-woocommerce/48865464#48865464), I've customized the code and tried this script:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', 'wcs_do_not_reduce_processing_stock', 10, 2 );
function wcs_do_not_reduce_processing_stock( $reduce_stock, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) && $order->get_payment_method() == 'cod' ) {
        $reduce_stock = false;
    }
    return $reduce_stock;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I avoid stock reduction on order items for orders using "Cash on delivery" payment method with a "processing" status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed a your code a bit and added the missing code that will reduce stock on "completed" order status for COD payment method only:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', 'processing_cod_stock_not_reduced', 20, 2 );
function processing_cod_stock_not_reduced( $reduce_stock, $order ) {
    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'completed' ) && $order->get_payment_method() == 'cod' ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $reduce_stock;
}

// Reduce stock on COD orders with completed status
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'order_stock_reduction_based_on_payment_method', 20, 2 );
function order_stock_reduction_based_on_payment_method( $order_id, $order ){
    if( $order->get_payment_method() == 'cod' && ! get_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_stock_reduced', true ) ){
        wc_reduce_stock_levels($order_id);
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

Comment: This code helps me a lot thanks sir! Saved my day. tried and tested